# How to do inline citations?

Tags: citing, bibentry

I have found the `bibentry` package but I can't get it to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@book{mittelbach2004latex,
  title={The LATEX companion},
  author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel and Braams, Johannes and Carlisle, David and Rowley, Chris},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

\end{filecontents} 


\begin{document}
    \nobibliography{mybib}
    Learn \LaTeX (\bibentry{mittelbach2004latex}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get a warning from natbib:

```
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you click a special button or press a special key to get the bibliography going?

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't quite understand what you mean. I wrote this is in Vim so no special buttons.

Comment: This has started to work. I am thinking it must have been a version thing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I come up with ignoring the `bibentry` package completely:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{mittelbach2004latex,
  title={The LATEX companion},
  author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel and Braams, Johannes and Carlisle, David and Rowley, Chris},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
    Learn \LaTeX~(\fullcite{mittelbach2004latex}).

\end{document}
```

[image]